# Is it possible to render json data into a javascript variable while making an ajax call in grails?

Tags: ajax, grails, gsp

Is it possible to render json data into a javascript variable while making an ajax call in grails?

I am using the [submitToRemote](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/submitToRemote.html) inorder to make an ajax call from my grails view to an action in my grails controller. The action returns a json variable/value. I need to to assign this value to a javascript variable for further usage on my web page. Is this possible to achieve? Any leads will be helpful.

Comment: Checkout the onsuccess param of `submitToRemote`. [Here's](http://blogs.bytecode.com.au/glen/2008/12/06/a-cute-tinyurl-codec.html) a example

Comment: Sérgio Michels : it works fine...only had to replace the 'e' with 'data'. I think jquery uses 'data'. Please could you put in the answer below so that I can select it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`submitToRemote` have the `onSuccess` option that you can use to retrieve the json data. From the docs:

> onSuccess (optional) - The JavaScript function to call if successful

An example of how doing it can be seen in [this blog post](http://blogs.bytecode.com.au/glen/2008/12/06/a-cute-tinyurl-codec.html).

Comment: this worked for me. Thanks Sérgio! Only thing for some reason, 'e' did not work for me, but 'data' did!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `onSuccess` callback of `submitToRemote` to read the result of your request and pass them into a javascript variable.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function passResult(result) {
        yourVariable = result.responseText      
    }
</script>

<g:form action="show">
    Login: <input name="login" type="text" />
    <g:submitToRemote update="updateMe" onSuccess="passResult(result)"/>
</g:form>

<div id="updateMe">this div will be updated with the form submit response</div>
```

The code above is untested but should work.